# Throttling reads from an SQS queue

Tags: mule, amazon-sqs

I have a Mule application which is reading off an SQS queue. I am trying to find a way to throttle my reading from the queue.

My requirement is to limit the time between polling from the queue and also to only read a single message at a time.

poll the queue every 10 seconds for only 1 new message

If set the following on the mule sqs:receive-messages connector would that correspond to what I'm after?

pollingPeriod
numberOfMessages

I'm a little unsure from reading the documenation whether pollingPeriod is for sqs long polling which is not what I want, or if it is actually to specify how often to poll.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty much aware of mule application but in general (keeping mule aside) the polling interval is a function of your application. So when I write my application I would put a sleep of whatever time interval I want between my polling and when that interval is over I would poll the SQS.

So if mule provides inbuilt scheduling then pollingPeriod can be the the parameter that controls the polling interval, else it necessarily has to be related to SQS Long Polling feature